# Footer to be always at bottom but not fixed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, footer

How can we make bootstrap footer always at the bottom but not fixed?

For example in the below code, the footer should be at the bottom. (the white space after footer should be before footer). This can be achieved by using *sticky-bottom*, but when there will be more content (when the page will be scrolled), it will be fixed will not be shown at last.

How to achieve that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>VN Parcel</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light self-navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="'.$website_address.'"><img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=VN&rounded=true&format=svg" alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;'.$title.'</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
      '.$website_slogan.'
    </ul>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto self-second-ul">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/91'.$website_wamobile.'"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> '.$website_wamobile.'</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="mailto:'.$website_email.'"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> '.$website_email.'</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tel:'.$website_mobile.'"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> '.$website_mobile.'</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div class="container p-3 bg-white rounded">


    <div class="row">
      <label for="Number">Track your parcel here <i class="far fa-hand-point-down far-blink"></i></label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="number" name="srch_num">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-addon2" value="Search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>





  <footer class="footer">
    <nav class="navbar bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light self-navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="'.$website_address.'"><img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=VN&rounded=true&format=svg" alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;'.$title.'</a>

      <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
        '.$website_slogan.'
      </ul>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto self-second-ul">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/91'.$website_wamobile.'"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> '.$website_wamobile.'</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="mailto:'.$website_email.'"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> '.$website_email.'</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tel:'.$website_mobile.'"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> '.$website_mobile.'</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8wLbsk3q/

Comment: @dave quite, but not quite. I think you can fix the bottom padding issue and post it as an answer https://jsfiddle.net/u5w4j2vn/

Comment: Yes I had the same problem and the only way I found is set min-height in body. I don't know if it's the best solution but it worked.

Comment: @dave When the footer is big, and the container has more text, it's not scrolling. https://jsfiddle.net/mepfq8cd/1/

Comment: maybe something like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/y72L69n1/. Otherwise you need to know how big the footer is and set the body padding-bottom to that number, so that the absolutely positioned footer won't be blocking things

Comment: @dave tried your CSS on the main code as in the question. But the to navbar is big. https://jsfiddle.net/mepfq8cd/3/

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is your footer is at the bottom of your body, but your body is smaller than your page

you should add a minimum height to your body with this css sample

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}
```

Comment: indeed, you have to set the position of your footer at the bottom, I edited my post

Comment: Umm, I decided to remove `<nav class="navbar bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light self-navbar">` and keep others as it is. While doing this I found that footer is overlapping the body.